# My Lcov command cannot write to a directory?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, gcov, lcov

What might be causing this sort of error? I am currently using lcov with Cygwin, and do not encounter any issues accessing/reading-from/writing-to the specified path when using gcc or any other Linux commands.

Just to demonstrate my exact process...

```
caffeine@ENG-INT /cygdrive/c/Users/caffeine/My Documents/$gcc -Wall -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -o cov.exe cov.c

caffeine@ENG-INT /cygdrive/c/Users/caffeine/My Documents/$ ./cov.exe

caffeine@ENG-INT /cygdrive/c/Users/caffeine/My Documents/$ lcov --capture --directory c:/Users/caffeine/My\ Documents --output-file coverage.info
```

*****That last command gives this output to the console, and I cannot wrap my head around it

```
Capturing coverage data from c:/Users/caffeine/My Documents
Found gcov version: 5.3.0
Scanning c:/Users/caffeine/My Documents for .gcda files ...
Found 1 data files in c:/Users/caffeine/My Documents
Processing cov.gcda
```

geninfo:

> ERROR: cannot write to directory /cygdrive/c/Users/caffeine/My Documents/c:/Users/caffeine/My Documents!

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem but a system problem.

Comment: as lcov seems a not cygwin program, try `--directory 'c:\Users\caffeine\My Documents'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR while code coverage report using lcov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675961/error-while-code-coverage-report-using-lcov)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37675961/783510).

There used to be a [bug in lcov 1.12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552483/783510) that lead to this error messsage. Fortunately, it is fixed now. Upgrading to 1.13 should fix the problem.