# ERROR while code coverage report using lcov

Tags: code-coverage, ubuntu-16.04, lcov

I am trying to run coverage on my project, after updating to Ubuntu 16.04.
I get

```
Deleted 665 files
Writing data to coverage.info.cleaned
lcov: ERROR: cannot write to coverage.info.cleaned!
CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/coverage' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage] Error 13
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'coverage' failed
make: *** [coverage] Error 2
enter code here
```

Before the update I had no problem running the coverage

Comment: Have you tried `make clean`?

Comment: Sure, I even re-make the Coverage directory

Comment: Found the problem, in my case at the end I have removed all the unnecessary outputs, and re-write them to a different file. After updating to 16.04 the new location to write the new data was at the root directory. It was  fixed by setting the new target

Comment: Thanks! Add that as an accepted answer. That helped me solve my problem. That has got to be a bug BTW....

Answer (score 5):

Does it help if you use **absolute paths instead of relative paths** when passing files to `lcov`?

I ran into a similiar problem where `lcov` also failed to write the file. 
Not sure if it is a bug in `lcov`, but the problem was that it got confused with relative paths:

```
lcov -a test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__base.info -a test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__test.info \
     -o test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__total.info
Combining tracefiles.
Reading tracefile test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__base.info
Reading tracefile test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__test.info
lcov: WARNING: function data mismatch at /home/phil/ghost/constants.h:1862
Writing data to test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__total.info
lcov: ERROR: cannot write to test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__total.info!
```

Running it with `strace` revealed that it executes `chdir("/")` on several locations, which changes the working directory to `/`. That explains why it cannot write the file.

One workaround is to use absolute paths. For instance, if you are using GNU make, you can use the `abspath` command:

```
lcov -a $(abspath test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__base.info) \
     -a $(abspath test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__test.info) \
     -o $(abspath test_fast_cxxtest_gcov__total.info)
```

After that change, it was finally able to write the file.

(Other options like trying to set the directories using the `--base-directory` or `--directory` option did not have an effect, as far as I saw.
The version of `lcov` that I tested with is 1.12.)

The problem is not limited to Ubuntu, as I ran into it on Arch Linux. It could be a regression introduced in 1.12, however, so I reported it (see [issue #77630](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77630)).

**Update:** Lcov is not part of GCC, so my original bug report was closed, but I got an answer from the Lcov mailing list. The problem is already fixed in commit [632c25](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/commit/632c25a0d1f5e4d2f4fd5b28ce7c8b86d388c91f). Users of Arch Linux based distros can try the latest snapshot with [aur/lcov-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lcov-git/).